# Buzilla vs Nunit

Tags: .net, visual-studio, testing, nunit, bugzilla

I am kind of new to .net can some one twll me diff b\w nunit vs buzilla vs Unit test(Visual studio) testing and team forge for TFS.Can Nunit and Unit Test do all that Bugzilla and Team Forge does?

Thanks

Comment: Bugzilla is not a unit testing platform. Nunit and MSTest are not bug tracking tools. What are you trying to compare?

Answer (score 2):

NUnit is a unit test framework. MSTest (the one with Visual Studio and TFS) is a unit test framework.

Bugzilla is a bug tracking database that has no direct corelation to unit testing. TFS does have a bug tracking database too.